# Effectiveness of laminated security glass

Tags: security, break-in

How effective is laminated security glass in preventing smash-and-grab break-ins?  Are particular brands or types more effective?

Comment: If you've seen side glass on Mercedes-Benz cars, you don't get smash and grab on those windows, lol. Actually, I assume you are talking about some type of aftermarket laminated glass, but what exactly are you talking about? Can you show us some examples? You are talking about the side windows? In what type of vehicle? Any other pertinent information you're not giving us?

Answer (score 1):

Laminated glass will not prevent a tooled-up person, intent on entry to a vehicle, from entering it. Laminated auto glass is essentially a safety measure. It does not shatter and splinter throwing bits of glass around on impact. To prevent entry, even by bullets, a special type of laminated 'glass' made from poly-carbonated plastics are used. These are extremely expensive, and are custom made-to-order.

Comment: I'm more concerned with someone intent on quickly stealing something without being seen, thus the mention of "smash-and-grab" theft. As I understand it, laminated glass helps to slow down entry. Is this true?

Comment: I had a woman come into our shop in hysterics. Her little boy had locked himself into her car. A centre punch on the glass struck with a hammer allowed entry in 10 seconds.

Comment: Okay, sounds like laminated glass works pretty well, then.  "It's very rare for a smash and grab auto burglary to take more than ten seconds."  http://www.americanownews.com/story/24418252/smash-and-grab  Also: getting entry into the vehicle (creating enough of an opening to reach in and unlock a door) would be less time-consuming than creating an opening big enough to pull a bag or other item through.

Answer (score 1):

Laminated glass WOULD slow down a casual opportunist, but then so would the absence of easy-to-find rocks, bricks, etc. It takes a hard, heavy object to break through nearly any side glass, so unless you frequent places where rocks are readily found, the only people who might smash-and-grab would be people who're already "armed" to the task - they may be carrying hammers, small battering rams (pipe with handles), and what-have-you.

Your single most secure course of action is to always leave the car empty of valuables that might tempt a thief, then leave the doors UNLOCKED. An unlocked door eliminates the need for any glass breakage... so even if someone got IN, at least you wouldn't have to replace thw windows.

Unless you have 3/8" or thicker solid polycarbonate or wired-glass windows, if I leave the house intent on getting into your car, I WILL GET INTO YOUR CAR... and it won't take me very long.

Comment: 'then leave the doors UNLOCKED. An unlocked door eliminates the need for any glass breakage... so even if someone got IN, at least you wouldn't have to replace thw windows' - They would need to replace the car instead ;)